# JavaFX MVC. I can't make just a little program with a simple button

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I'm trying to make and javaFx application with MVC architecture but i'm stuck at the start with a bizzare "for me" problem.
I have found a nice guide for java swing but nothing for Javafx.

I want my main to be realy simple like that in this example i have found in this site:
http://www.newthinktank.com/2013/02/mvc-java-tutorial/

I have made this 2 versions.The firs work without errors but I don't like it and the second I want give me errors.

Version 1:

```
package mvc.calc;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class View extends Application {

  public void go() {
    launch();
  }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("hi");
    Button btn = new Button("sum");  
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 250);
    grid.add(btn, 0, 0);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);   
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

and the main:

```
package mvc.calc;

public class Calc{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    View v = new View();
    v.go();      
  }
}
```

Version 2:

```
package mvc.calc;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class View extends Application {

  public View(){
    go();
  }

  public void go() {
    launch();
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("hi");
    Button btn = new Button("sum");  
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 250);
    grid.add(btn, 0, 0);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);   
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

and the main:

```
package mvc.calc;

public class Calc{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    View v = new View();       
  }
}
```

but i got tons of errors.
Some one can help me with that mvc?

Comment: Tons of errors? Which ones and where?

Comment: Consider this, should your application contain anything other then your primary scene/view (ie each of your views should be independent of the application class)

Comment: Personally, I don't like showing the UI from within the constructor, it doesn't allow you to preconfigure the state before it's launched

Comment: The errores:
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class mvc.calc.View
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$1/140435067.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

And also others

I really don't know how to use this mvc in javafx, i have alway done all different but i have to make something with mvc.

Comment: I don't really see how you are implementing an MVC architecture here. Which is the model? The controller? But at any rate, I think you are misunderstanding the role of the `Application` subclass, which is really your "main" class, i.e. it is the startup. It should do the minimal possible work, just have a `start()` method which instantiates your model, view, and controller (however you choose to represent them), and then displays the view.

Comment: Also, please post the full stack trace in the question, and identify the lines where the errors occur.

Comment: The full stack error is too long, but the error is at the first line of the main when i try to instantiate View().
But it's strange that it works if i call the method v.go() from the main but it don't works if i call the method go() form the View() constructor.
So you think that it's better not to have a View() subclass of Application?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Your view should not be a subclass of `Application`. (Just think of it semantically: a view is not an application.) As for the error, you should be able to edit your question (not post a comment) to include the full stack trace.